# Вектор линейного градиента

Tags: svg, градиент

Определяю градиент от красного к зеленому через желтый, а посередине - синий. С вектором направления (0, 0) - (100%, 100%)

```
  <linearGradient id="gradGreen" x0="0" y0="0" x1="100%" y1="100%">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red"/>
    <stop offset="49%" stop-color="yellow"/>
    <stop offset="50%" stop-color="blue"/>
    <stop offset="51%" stop-color="yellow"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="green"/>
  </linearGradient>
```

и привязываю его к треугольнику

```
<path d="M 100,0 200,200 0,200" fill="url(#gradGreen)"/>
```

получаю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос, почему градиент распространяется от нижнего основания к верхнему углу? Я рассчитывал что он пойдет от левой стороны к правому углу. Как воспринимать вектор направления?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы немного ошиблись в формуле градиента.
Update  <strike>Поэтому  был применен градиент по умолчанию - сверху вниз.</strike>

Необходимо было написать:
`<linearGradient id="gradGreen" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="100%">`

```html
 <svg width="405" height="405" viewBox="0 0 405 405" style="border:1px solid red;">
 <defs>
 <linearGradient id="gradGreen" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="100%">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red"/>
    <stop offset="49%" stop-color="yellow"/>
    <stop offset="50%" stop-color="blue"/>
    <stop offset="51%" stop-color="yellow"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="green"/>
  </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <path d="M 100,0 200,200 0,200" fill="url(#gradGreen)"/> 
  <path transform="translate(205 0)" d="M 200,0 200,200 0,200" fill="url(#gradGreen)"/> 
  
  <rect x="205" y="205" width="200" height="200" fill="url(#gradGreen)" />
```

К вашему коду я добавил ещё две фигуры: прямоугольный треугольник и квадрат.
 Ко всем трем фигурам применён одинаковый градиент.
 Рисунок показывает, что начало действия градиента - левый верхний угол - `x1="0%"`, `y1="0%"` прямоугольной области, внутри которой находится фигура - треугольник. Направление распространения градиента - правый нижний угол прямоугольной области, в которой находится треугольник `x2="100%"` `y2="100%"`

Comment: Мдя. Не обращал внимания, что вектор не от нулевой точки к первой, а от первой ко второй

Comment: Только у меня применился снизу вверх. По идее, вторую точку он таки воспринял. А умолчательный - слева направо

Comment: @AntonShchyrov да, вы правы, по умолчанию градиент слева направо применяется. Проверяется легко - просто убираются все координаты из объявления градиента. Сейчас уберу из ответа свою ошибку